# Matching comparison operators indefinitely in a string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match the following pattern:

```
bla bla bla lorem ipsum bla bla email=destiney41@leuschke.org name!=Foo Bar
```

Here's my current approach:

```
(email|name)+\s*(>=|<=|>|<|=|!=)\s*([^ !=<>]+)
```

Since I'll always know the keys (email, name), the first part is easy, but I'm unable to match values with whitespace. What am I missing here?

The end of a match should be the beginning of a new key + operator combination.

Comment: How can you describe/define the end of a match?

Comment: _"I'm unable to match values with whitespace"_ Because you're explicitly including a space in your inverted set `[^ !=<>]`. If a value with whitespace isn't quoted or escaped, how do you know when it ends?

Comment: The end of a match should be the beginning of a new key + operator combination.

Comment: Try `(email|name)\s*([><]=?|!?=)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:(?:email|name)\s*(?:[><]=?|!?=)|$))` then (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/YUzlnz/1)).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Feel free to submit an answer, because this one is it! :)

Comment: With subpattern references: [`(email|name)+\s*([><]=?|!?=)\s*(.*?)(?=(?1)\s*(?2)|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/myUKbO/1) (similar @WiktorStribiżew's answer). But this is more a cosmetic thing :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(email|name)\s*([><]=?|!?=)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:(?:email|name)\s*(?:[><]=?|!?=)|$))
```

Or, if the keys must be matched as whole words:

```
\b(email|name)\s*([><]=?|!?=)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:\b(?:email|name)\s*(?:[><]=?|!?=)|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YUzlnz/1). *Details*:

- `\b(email|name)` - a word boundary and Group 1 capturing either `email` or `name`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([><]=?|!?=)` - Group 2: `<` or `>` and then an optional `=`, or an optional `!` and then a `=` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:\b(?:email|name)\s*(?:[><]=?|!?=)|$))` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current position):

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `\b(?:email|name)\s*(?:[><]=?|!?=)` - either `email` or `name` as a whole word, then  zero or more whitespaces and then a `<` or `>` and then an optional `=`, or an optional `!` and then a `=` char
  - `|` - or

    - `$` - end of string
  - `)` - end of the group.